# Android acitity layout is corrupted if user type into text input

Tags: android, android-layout

i faced with problem on some devices in my app, if user starts typing text into the text field and virtual keyboard is displayed is screen corrupted (see screenshot). On some devices is everything O.K.

How could i solve this issue?

[image]

Here is code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/mainActLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- LOGO BACKGROUND -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoBackgroundImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150sp"
        android:background="@color/lighter_blue"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

    <!-- LOGO -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImgIV"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/appmainlogo" />

    <!-- EU FLAG IMG BUTTON -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/euFlagImgBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/euflag" />

    <!-- CAR PLATE ID TEXT INPUT -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/carPlateIdEditText"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/insert_car_plate_number"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submiBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:background="@color/lighter_blue"
        android:onClick="checkSpz"
        android:text="@string/check"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- FIRST ICON -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstIconTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:text="@string/icon_safe"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <!-- SECOND ICON -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondIconTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="@string/icon_quick"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <!-- THIRD ICON -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdIconTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="@string/icon_quality"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

<!-- HEADING TV -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/safeDescTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:text="@string/safe"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quickDescTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="@string/quick"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qualityDescTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="@string/quality"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: your handling is not Generic of layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to putup scrollview as a root of layout.then use following code snippet.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Through manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Where i should to put in? In onCreate and in manifest in application tag?

Comment: I prefer programmatically.